# Why does iOS allow using passkey without biometric?

Tags: ios, biometrics, passkey

One of the touted features of passkeys is that they depend on a biometric in order to use them. However, on an iPhone, if the finger-print scanner isn’t successful, it offers you the option of using your passcode. Couldn't one then brute force the passcode?

Comment: Isn't there always a backup to biometrics?

Comment: In this case, maybe there shouldn't be.

Comment: But your question is "why" not "doncha think there shouldn't be?" And before passkeys, brute force was a risk, but even the FBI couldn't crack it (10 failures erased the device), so, with this last comment, I'm not sure this is an actual question but a drumming up for support of an idea.

Comment: Well my assumption was that biometrics are more secure than passcodes but reading around it seems that this is not the case.

Comment: I googled "iphone passkeys biometric" and the top result is: https://developer.apple.com/passkeys/#:~:text=Works%20alongside%20passwords,transition%20to%20passkeys%20is%20seamless. So, I think this is answered by a simple google search.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is answered y Apple's documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the passcode can be brute forced but the OS has anti-hammering built in which provides an extra level of protection

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).